# Twilio Dial transfer failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

In my app I am attempting to transfer the call to a different phone number.  Currently it redirects to the correct xml page, says transferring to an agent, and then the call just hangs up.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here, would love an extra set of eyes.

routes.rb

```
post 'call_logs/connect' => 'call_logs#connect'
post 'call_logs/directions' => 'call_logs#directions'
```

controller

```
def connect
  @post_to = BASE_URL + "/directions"
  render :action => "reminder.xml.builder", :layout => false
end

def directions

  if params['Digits'] == '1'
    render :action => "transfer.xml.builder", :layout => false
    return
  end
end
```

transfer.xml.builder

```
xml.instruct!
xml.Response do
  xml.Gather(:action => @post_to, :numDigits => 1) do
    xml.Say "transferring you to an agent"
    xml.Dial "+12142222222", :timeout => "60", :callerID => 'MY_TWILIO_NUMBER'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The problem is that [you cannot use a `<Dial>` verb inside of the `<Gather>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#nesting-rules). I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve with that setup, but that's why it is just hanging up.

Let me know if I can help any further.